# Comparing two groups with hundreds of variables?

Tags: regression, t-test

I am a physician looking for help with research. I am looking to learn the best way to analyze my data. I thought it would be simple enough, but after speaking to a colleague and doing my own research, it seems a little more complicated.

Basically, the project entails me taking a about 100 patients and looking at their resected tumor. Now, either the tumor will be positive for gene X or negative for that gene. So, you have two groups, gene X positive, and gene X negative. Then what I am going to do is look at the medical imaging that was done of that tumor, say a CT scan. I will take that image for each patient and run it through a high-thruput software that will give me variables about the image beyond what I could see with the naked eye. Say this software gives me numeric values for 150 variables for each tumor, ideally, I would just look at each variable one by one and see if there is a difference in the variable between tumors positive for gene X and those that are negative for gene X. For ex, for each image I will have a numeric value for variable 1, I can then take the average across all variable 1s for the subset of gene X  positive and compare it to the variable 1 average for the gene X negative group and see if there is any statistical difference, and so on and so forth for the 150 variables.  The big idea being which of these medical image variables can help me predict which tumor will gene X positive or negative.

I think the issue with doing a T test for each variable is that in doing my research, looking at each variable individually will yield false positives since I am looking at so many variables. To correct for the high alpha, I looked into Benjamini-Hochberg Method, but in speaking with my colleague he suggested I analyze the data with something like a regression model but I do not have much experience with that and I am unsure if that is really right for my data. Hence, I looking for some help. Would it be so bad to do a T test for each of the 150 variables and see which is significantly different or not, what else can I do?

Comment: What is your aim? Do you want a classification method to predict positive/negative from your 150 variables, or do you rather want to make statements about the importance of the indivudual variables, or do you rather want to know whether your two classes are significantly different on your variables *in any way*? These are different problems and will require different methods. If you want optimal classification, you need classification algorithms (of which there are many), not tests.

Comment: I am essentially fishing to find out if the positive and negative gene tumors differ in any of these 150 variables. Once I know that, then I can try and predict positive/negative from those few variables that I know were statistically significant between the two. In reality, the two tumor types pos and negative, may not differ in these variables at all, but this is a start to a way to use imaging to predict if a tumor is gene X pos

Comment: Better add essential information to the question rather than writing it only in comments.